# Removing lines from image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am a beginner in OpenCV, I need to remove the horizontal and vertical lines in the image so that only the text remains ( The lines were causing trouble when extracting text in ocr ). I am trying to extract text from the Nutrient Fact Table. Can anyone help me?

[image: Nutrient Fact Table]

Comment: Instead of viewing the lines as an "obstacle", have you tried treating them as contours, or using an edge detector, to pass the contents of the rectangles formed by the lines? E.g. "Nutrition information..." would be one box, and the macro nutrient breakdown would be another box

Comment: @TrésDuBiel Yes i have tried tht, but some Nutrient Fact Table has vertical lines between Nutrient and its value, like Fats | 2.7g, the vertical line between creates an obstacle

Comment: For detecting lines, you can use [hough lines](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) of opencv.

Comment: I also recommend that you check [this link](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/how-to-flatten-the-image-of-a-label-on-a-food-jar) and [this one](http://study.marearts.com/2015/03/image-warping-using-opencv.html), perhaps you can warp the labels to be more rectangular.

Answer (score 3):

This was an interesting question, so I gave it a shot. Below I will show you how to extract and remove horizontal and vertical lines. You could extrapolate from it. Also, for sake of saving time, I did not preprocess your image to crop out the background as one should, which is an avenue for improvement.

The result: [image: result]
The code (edit: added vertical lines):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int, char** argv)
{
    // Load the image
    Mat src = imread(argv[1]);
    // Check if image is loaded fine
    if(!src.data)
        cerr << "Problem loading image!!!" << endl;
    Mat gray;
    if (src.channels() == 3)
    {
        cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    }
    else
    {
        gray = src;
    }

    //inverse binary img
    Mat bw;
    //this will hold the result, image to be passed to OCR
    Mat fin;
    //I find OTSU binarization best for text.
    //Would perform better if background had been cropped out
    threshold(gray, bw, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV | THRESH_OTSU);
    threshold(gray, fin, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY | THRESH_OTSU);
    imshow("binary", bw);
    Mat dst;
    Canny( fin, dst, 50, 200, 3 );
    Mat str = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3,3));
    dilate(dst, dst, str, Point(-1, -1), 3);
    imshow("dilated_canny", dst);
    //bitwise_and w/ canny image helps w/ background noise
    bitwise_and(bw, dst, dst);
    imshow("and", dst);
    Mat horizontal = dst.clone();
    Mat vertical = dst.clone();
    fin = ~dst;

    //Image that will be horizontal lines
    Mat horizontal = bw.clone();
    //Selected this value arbitrarily
    int horizontalsize = horizontal.cols / 30;
    Mat horizontalStructure = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(horizontalsize,1));
    erode(horizontal, horizontal, horizontalStructure, Point(-1, -1));
    dilate(horizontal, horizontal, horizontalStructure, Point(-1, -1), 1);
    imshow("horizontal_lines", horizontal);

    //Need to find horizontal contours, so as to not damage letters
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    vector<vector<Point> >contours;
    findContours(horizontal, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for (const auto& c : contours)
    {
        Rect r = boundingRect(c);

        float percentage_height = (float)r.height / (float)src.rows;
        float percentage_width = (float)r.width / (float)src.cols;

        //These exclude contours that probably are not dividing lines
        if (percentage_height > 0.05)
            continue;

        if (percentage_width < 0.50)
            continue;
        //fills in line with white rectange
        rectangle(fin, r, Scalar(255,255,255), CV_FILLED);
    }

    int verticalsize = vertical.rows / 30;
    Mat verticalStructure = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(1,verticalsize));
    erode(vertical, vertical, verticalStructure, Point(-1, -1));
    dilate(vertical, vertical, verticalStructure, Point(-1, -1), 1);
    imshow("verticalal", vertical); 

    findContours(vertical, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for (const auto& c : contours)
    {
        Rect r = boundingRect(c);

        float percentage_height = (float)r.height / (float)src.rows;
        float percentage_width = (float)r.width / (float)src.cols;

        //These exclude contours that probably are not dividing lines
        if (percentage_width > 0.05)
            continue;

        if (percentage_height < 0.50)
            continue;
        //fills in line with white rectange
        rectangle(fin, r, Scalar(255,255,255), CV_FILLED);
    }

    imshow("Result", fin);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The limitations of this approach are that the lines need to be straight. Due to the curve in the bottom line, it cuts slightly into "E" in "Energy". Perhaps with a hough line detection like suggested (I've never used it), a similar but more robust approach could be devised. Also, filling in the lines with rectangles probably is not the best approach.